# Wifi "button" - recommendation

Tags: wifi, home-security

Is there a wifi product that is a simple alarm button? When pressed it would notify my PC through my local wireless network, so i can autosend and email or other message through the web.

Generally I am looking for a WIFI product (not just 'wireless', that is not part of any larger integrated 'system', that is a simple button. Essentially like a panic button. Once pressed, it would send a message through the wifi router to the local PC so software could take over to take actions.

I just can't seem to find anything that is a simple switch ... as opposed to 'system'.  Any suggestions?

The closest thing I have seen is using a standard wifi video cam (like FOSCAM) - where it sends an email (or other) when motion is detected.  This is very close, except of course I don't want a camera - just a button.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer, because it's not dedicated hardware and involves software work, but the [$5 Amazon buttons can be used to do your bidding.](https://medium.com/@edwardbenson/how-i-hacked-amazon-s-5-wifi-button-to-track-baby-data-794214b0bdd8#.itdeqcrcl)

Comment: It's not quite the solution I am looking for - but it is a damn interesting solution.  and it also proves wrong the many "experts" who say that this is impossible.
I wonder if creating a hardware hack from an arduino board would do it easily and cheaply ... or if the Amazon button is expensive but subsidized so they can make it up in product sales.